# What is the exact frequency of PWM signals produced from Arduino pins

Tags: arduino, pwm, arduino-uno

In http://arduino.cc/en/Reference/analogWrite it says,

" The frequency of the PWM signal on most pins is approximately 490 Hz. On the Uno and similar boards, pins 5 and 6 have a frequency of approximately 980 Hz. Pins 3 and 11 on the Leonardo also run at 980 Hz. "

I want now to check that frequency. Simply I typed this command `analogWrite(9,127)`, which will generate PWM signal with duty cycle 50%.

Then I used the pulseIn built-in Arduino function ([pulseIn descriotion](http://arduino.cc/en/Reference/pulseIn)) and typed this command `pulseIn(9,HIGH)` to measre the period in which the signal is HIGH. It returns in average **1010 us**.

So the period time is **2020** (1010 for the High period and 1010 for the low period) and consequently the PWM frequency from that pin is 495.04 ~ **495Hz**.

The same is done with pin number 5. The High period is **506 uS**, The full period is **1012 uS**, The PWM frequency from that pin is 988.14 Hz ~ **988 Hz**.

*So, What is the exact PWM frequency ?!*

The following pictures is snapshots for the Arduino sketch and the results

**The Arduino sketch**

[image: The Arduino sketch]

**When I pressed '1' multiple times**

[image: When I pressed '1' multiple times]

**When I pressed '0' multiple times**

[image: When I pressed '0' multiple times]

Answer (score 1):

PWM signals are created by timers. A timer increments a register, and various methods create a square signal based on that.

The frequency depends on 3 things:

- the master clock: 8MHz or 16MHz usually on Arduino)
- the prescale (or divisor on the page below): to slow down the frequency, you can setup the timer to increase the count every 1, 2, 4, 8, 16… master clock cycles
- the maximum count: there are several counting methods, but an important limit is the register size (usually 8 bits and 16 bits on Arduino)

You'll find specific details on this page: 
http://playground.arduino.cc/Main/TimerPWMCheatsheet

Answer (score 0):

> So, What is the exact PWM frequency ?!

imo There are to many variables to give the "exact" PWM frequency between boards and other factors.

For example, if I were to test two different boards from the same company I would not be able to get an exact match.

Answer (score -1):

You've used one of the two pins where the PWM signal works at 980hz! 
More specifically the pin 5 and 6!

This is what the website of Arduino says:

> The frequency of the PWM signal on most pins is approximately 490 Hz.
>   On the Uno and similar boards, pins 5 and 6 have a frequency of
>   approximately 980 Hz.

http://arduino.cc/en/Reference/analogWrite